# Read the contents of a text file every 15 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, partial-page-refresh

I'm working on a music site:
I have a text file on the server which contains the name of the currently playing song. 
I would like read the text file  every fifteeen seconds, and change the text displayed on my site,
without a refresh.

Now, using a little jQuery and javascript, I have actually gotten to the point where the file is read and displayed the first time, but it wont refresh . I have attempted all sorts of setInterval functions, but for the life of me I cant get this part to work. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get('http://www.XXXXX.com/nowplaying/NowPlaying.txt', function(data) {
        var myvar = data;
        var parts = myvar.split(/\n/);
        var songtitle = parts[0];
        var songartist = parts[1];
        var songalbum = parts[2];
        var songtime = parts[3];
        $('#songtitleholder').html(songtitle);
        $('#songartistholder').html(songartist);
        $('#songalbumholder').html(songalbum);
    });
});​
</script>
```

Comment: On a side note, you should consider saving information like this in a database instead of a text file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the code you want to execute `repeatedly` in function and pass that function in [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). The second parameter of setTimeout will take interval in `millisecond`.

Using setTimeout here IMO is more `appropriate` here as It will exclude the time taken for send request and receiving response. It will `send request every 5 second after receiving response.`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

 $(document).ready(function() {

    function functionToLoadFile(){
      jQuery.get('http://www.XXXXX.com/nowplaying/NowPlaying.txt', function(data) {
       var myvar = data;
       var parts = myvar.split(/\n/);
       var songtitle = parts[0];
       var songartist = parts[1];
       var songalbum = parts[2];
       var songtime = parts[3];

       $('#songtitleholder').html(songtitle);
       $('#songartistholder').html(songartist);
       $('#songalbumholder').html(songalbum);
       setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 5000);
    });
    }

    setTimeout(functionToLoadFile, 10);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This works beautifully! thank you. Is there a way to read the target text file as soon as one would land on the page, display it, THEN refresh? As it stands now, the song title label sits blank for a few seconds (which I can TOTALLY live with). Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: I have updated my answer, it will load as soon as the page is loaded and reload after 5 seconds. Using setTimeout here IMO is more appropriate here as It will exclude the time take for send request and receiving response. It will send request every 5 second after receiving response.

Comment: this  worked perfectly for me. Thank you. This place is awesome! I thought I was gunna be stuck until after the holidays!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to wrap your example in a setInterval call like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval( function(){
    jQuery.get('http://www.XXXXX.com/nowplaying/NowPlaying.txt', function(data) {
        var myvar = data;
        var parts = myvar.split(/\n/);
        var songtitle = parts[0];
        var songartist = parts[1];
        var songalbum = parts[2];
        var songtime = parts[3];
        $('#songtitleholder').html(songtitle);
        $('#songartistholder').html(songartist);
        $('#songalbumholder').html(songalbum);
    });
    }, 15000);
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a function and call it with `setInterval` (*you might want to add a timestamp to the URL so that the result does not cache*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function refresh(){
        jQuery.get('http://www.XXXXX.com/nowplaying/NowPlaying.txt', { "t": $.now() }, function(data) {
            var myvar = data,
                parts = myvar.split(/\n/),
                songtitle = parts[0],
                songartist = parts[1],
                songalbum = parts[2],
                songtime = parts[3];

            $('#songtitleholder').html(songtitle);
            $('#songartistholder').html(songartist);
            $('#songalbumholder').html(songalbum);
        });
    }
    setInterval(refresh, 15000);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this?

```
    window.setInterval(function(){

    /// call your function here

    }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `setTimeout`. `setInterval` tends to get queued when window loses focus while switching browser tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getData();
});​

function getData() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery.get('http://www.XXXXX.com/nowplaying/NowPlaying.txt', function(data) {
            var myvar = data;
            var parts = myvar.split(/\n/);
            var songtitle = parts[0];
            var songartist = parts[1];
            var songalbum = parts[2];
            var songtime = parts[3];
            $('#songtitleholder').html(songtitle);
            $('#songartistholder').html(songartist);
            $('#songalbumholder').html(songalbum);

            /* repeat getData*/
            getData();
        });
    }, 15000)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `setInterval` as per everyone else's answers, make sure the file isn't being cached by requesting:

```
jQuery.get("http://......./NowPlaying.txt?t="+new Date().getTime(), function....);
```

Comment: jQuery will automatically add a timestamp to url

Comment: @charlietfl, not it will not.. default for `cache` option is true, except for `script` and `jsonp`. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: ive got my answer. Do I need to close this question or something?